# UIScrollView does not work

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I made `UIImageView` that is embed in `ScrollView`. Size of the `UIImageView` is bigger than default space. I wrote:

```
_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 2000);
```

in `.m` class after I had made "scrollView" outlet in `.h` . When I run application, I see just the frist part of my image without ability to scroll. Likely it's scrolled somehow specially. Do I have some problems with code?

Comment: Have you tried this: `_scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;`  ?

Comment: The evil auto layout :P. Try disabling it. :)

Comment: I tried both ways. It just changes size of the image(or location) but I can not scroll. How can I scroll in simulator?

Comment: In simulator you can scroll doing "drag and drop" actions using mouse.

Comment: I don't have a mouse:( only macbooks trackpad.

Comment: But it doesn't matter, do the same with trackpad ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the trackpad place you cursor on the area that you normally would use for your finger. Press the ctrl and drag your finger on the trackpad down/up simultaneously.